# Use of regularity of the PDE solution to argue the smoothness of a function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I asked the question below before.

[$\Delta u$ is bounded. Can we say $u\in C^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371181/delta-u-is-bounded-can-we-say-u-in-c1/1371233#1371233)

I thought I understood the discussion using the PDE theory at the time but now I am lost. I am going to a similar but different question given the answer above.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ an open bounded set consider a function $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ we happen to have.

Following the answer above I wish to apply the discussion on the regularity of the PDE solution to see the smoothness of $u$.

Let $\partial \Omega$ be $C^2$, say.

Suppose we know that
$\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$ with $\Delta$ being the distributional derivative.

### **Can we say $u\in H^2(\Omega)$?**

I felt that to say the smoothness we need some behaviour on the boundary.
E.g., [Gilbarg--Trudinger p. 186, Theorem 8.12](https://books.google.com/books?id=l9L6CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=gilbarg%20trudinger&hl=ja&pg=PA186#v=onepage&q&f=false)  says

> Let us assume ... and that there exists a function $\varphi\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ for which $u-\varphi\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$. Then, we have also $u\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ and
>
> $$
> \|u\|_{W^{2,2}}\le C(\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|\varphi\|_{W^{2,2}(\Omega)}
> $$

Now, we consider $f:=\Delta u$. I thought to apply this discussion we need to have some sort of $\varphi$. But we do not have information on the behaviour on the function $u$ that we happen to have. In the answer I accepted above it is said that it suffice to consider the zero boundary case, which I think is true for the PDE, but I do not see how it is ok here.

Comment: I would suggest that you specify the sense in which you are applying the Laplacian to your function.  You're asking if $$\Delta u =f$$ and $$f$$ is bounded implies that $$u \in C^1$$.  What you're not specifying is in what sense $$\Delta u =f$$.  Is it a weak solution, a strong solution, a viscosity solution, a distributional solution, a classical solution..?

Comment: @Glitch Thank you and sorry for my late reply. I have been busy and I wanted to understand you comment as accurate as possible. I updated the question and I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any information about the boundary values of $u$, then you only get local regularity $u\in H^2_{loc}(\Omega)$, but no information about the smoothness up to the boundary (check for instance Evans' book).

Comment: That is what I thought. But @ tankonetoone commented that "The requirement on trace zero is fine....", then I replied to that, still confused, and leaded me to the current question.