# Derivative of highest order is enough for the Sobolev norm?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Thinking about the partial derivative in this question [$\Delta u$ is bounded. Can we say $u\in C^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371181/delta-u-is-bounded-can-we-say-u-in-c1) of mine, I encountered this post.

[Equivalent Norms on Sobolev Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101021/equivalent-norms-on-sobolev-spaces?rq=1)

1. I wonder if this hold when $\alpha\neq 2$ as well.
2. Too many details are omitted in this post. Could I ask a reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

This is actually an general idea for space involving several order of derivatives: "**the extreme terms in a sum often already suffice to control the intermediate terms**". Notice that by extreme we mean both highest order and the lowest order.

For example, $W^{3,p}$ norm of $u$ can be controlled by using only $L^p$ norm of $u$ and the $L^p$ norm of 3rd derivative of $u$.

This idea also applied on space $C^p(\Omega)$, the continuous differentiable function space of order $p$ with $L^\infty$ norm. Also, Holder space is applied as well.

For a good reference of this idea, I would suggest you to read this [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/) by Terence Tao, look for exercise 2 for more explanation.

Also, for Equivalent Norms on Sobolev spaces, first look at this [post](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~panl/Pan_Liu/Useful_Resouce_files/Theorems.pdf), Theorem 2.7 for a summarization, look this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120441438), page 133, theorem 5.2 for details proof. (The proof is not short)

Comment: Just adding Theorem 5.2 in Adams--Fournier 2nd ed is on p. 135 at least in the one I have.