# Equivalent Sobolev Norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f$ be in the Sobolev space $H^s(\Omega)$. Then the standard definition of the norm is
\begin{equation}
||f||_{H^s}^2 = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq  s} ||D^{\alpha} f||_{L^2}^2 \qquad\qquad\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
when $s$ is a positive integer. With Fourier transform, an equivalent norm is formulated as
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{H^s}^2=\int|\hat f(\xi)|^2(1+|\xi|^2)^sd\xi\qquad\qquad\qquad(2)
\end{equation}
where $s$ can be extended to any positive real numbers. My question is whether $(2)$ is equivalent to the following norm
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{H^s}^2=\int|\hat f(\xi)|^2(1+|\xi|^{2s})d\xi\qquad\qquad\qquad(3)
\end{equation}
The following is my attempt for proving $(1+|\xi|^2)^s\approx1+|\xi|^{2s}$. Notice that for any positive number $a$, if $0<s<1$, then $(1+a)^s\leq 1+a^s$ and if $1\leq s$, then $(1+a)^s\leq 2^{s-1}(1+a^s)$. When $0<s<1$, we have
$$
(1+a)^{1/s}\leq 2^{\frac{1}{s}-1}(1+a^{1/s})
$$
which leads to
$$
1+b^s\leq 2^{1-s}(1+b)^s \quad \
$$
for any positive number $b$. So in the case of $0<s<1$, we have
$$
1+|\xi|^{2s}\lesssim(1+|\xi|^2)^s\leq 1+|\xi|^{2s}.
$$
The case of $1\leq s$ is similar. Is there anything wrong here?

And I also see an equivalent norm defined by (for example see
[equivalent norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101021/equivalent-norms-on-sobolev-spaces))
$$ ||f||_{H^s}^2 = ||f||_{L^2}^2 + \sum_{|\alpha| =  s} ||D^{\alpha} f||_{L^2}^2. \qquad\qquad\qquad(4)$$ By $\|f\|_2=\|\hat f\|_2$ and $(\hat{f^{(s)}})(\xi)=(2\pi i\xi)^s\hat f(\xi)$, (4) is truely equivalent to $(3)$. So are $(1),(2),(3),(4)$ equivalent for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ or $\Omega$ being a interval?